# html5 content not styled in JavascriptMVC+Modernizr

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, html, modernizr

I'm using Modernizr and JavascriptMVC.

Modernizr is in the head section.

`<script src="./resources/js/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>`

And steal before closing body:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='../steal/steal.js?formcms,development'></script>`

When I add some html5 content in the controller like this:
`$('body').append(this.view('header'))`

It is not styled.

Is there a solution to style html5 elements after adding them in a view in JavascriptMVC?
I'm using IE6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**innerShiv**](http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/).

```
<script src="http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/innershiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then

```
$('body').append(innerShiv(this.view('header')));
```

Comment: When I add the innerShiv script to the html5 document it works, but when I add after it the steal script it throws an error.